# Android: TextView enable links but open them inside the app

Tags: android, url

I know how to open URL links inside the app (I use [FinestWebView](https://github.com/TheFinestArtist/FinestWebView-Android)).

Also, I know how to make URLs in a TextView clickable (`android:autoLink="web"`).

---

But I want to "combine" these two things, i.e. I want a URL link in a TextView to open inside the app when I click on it.

I didn't find anything on this, so: How can this be achieved?

Comment: Open webView inside you app by getting URL from clickable textView

Comment: Not sure if I understand your answer correctly. Do you mean I should make the TextView clickable and then after it is clicked, just open the URL how I would do it "normally" given an URL? This is not a good solution: I can only have one URL per TextView. And it doesn't matter anymore where the user clicks. But it should only open if the user clicks exactly on the URL, not anywhere on the TextView (it is this way if you use `android:autoLink="web"`).

Answer (score -1):

Do you want the link to be open from the webview!?
Just make it clear . Or provide some of your code stuffs..so that it can be easy to help yu